# Was universe spawn from nothing?

Tags: universe, big-bang-theory, singularity, infinite

**Was universe spawn from nothing?**

Until now, scientists figured out that the Big Bang happened from a tiny particle which was infinitely energy densed and having infinite mass. If that is the case where does that particle came from? Whats the current explanations based on current knowledge?

Comment: Pretty much all your assumptions of the current state of cosmology are wrong. In particular the "tiny particle" and "Infinite small size" and "infinite mass" are not in the current theory.   As stated the question is pretty much unanswerable. I think you should read up a little: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang

Comment: @James sorry for the unwanted word ‘small’. However, wiki also refers the initial form as "primeval atom" which I meant by the word ‘particle’. Also i still know that form of matter was infinitely dense and mass. Anyway, expecting an answer. Thanks.

Comment: With an unspecified size, an infinite density does not necessarily lead to infinite mass. The mass of the universe clearly is finite (yet large)